# docker inspect - format its output as a table

Tags: docker, formatting, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

How to use `--format` option of `docker inspect` to get its output as a table.
Following the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/formatting/#table) I used `--format 'table ...'` as an option with `docker ps` and it worked fine, but `docker inspect` seems to ignore it.

example:

```
echo "docker ps as table"
docker ps -a --format 'table {{.Names}}\t{{.Image}}'

echo "docker inspect as table"
docker ps --quiet | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker inspect \
--format 'table {{.Name}}\t{{.Config.Image}}'
```

produces the output:

```
docker ps as table
NAMES                     IMAGE
tmp-php-7.3-cli-buster    tmp-php:7.3-cli-buster
tmp-mysql-8.0.19-client   mysql:8
tmp-mysql-8.0.19          tmp-mysql:8.0.19
tmp-nginx-1.17.8          tmp-nginx:1.17.8
tmp-php-7.3-fpm-buster    tmp-php:7.3-fpm-buster
tmp-node-13.8.0-buster    tmp-node:13.8.0-buster
docker inspect as table
table /tmp-php-7.3-cli-buster\ttmp-php:7.3-cli-buster
table /tmp-mysql-8.0.19-client\tmysql:8
table /tmp-mysql-8.0.19\ttmp-mysql:8.0.19
table /tmp-nginx-1.17.8\ttmp-nginx:1.17.8
table /tmp-php-7.3-fpm-buster\ttmp-php:7.3-fpm-buster
table /tmp-node-13.8.0-buster\ttmp-node:13.8.0-buster
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `docker inspect` currently can't ouput tables, see this GitHub issue:

- https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/1103#issuecomment-402138813

I got here because I've tried to output table too, but unfortunately, all I can do is quote the comment from the issue:

> TLDR; `docker inspect` deals with JSON output and thus JSON output templates, versus the formatting strings you'd expect from other commands (such as `docker stats`)
> ...
> Which is essentially why table isn't working as expected and coming back as raw.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get a "table"-like output similar to `docker stats`. Mainly by utilizing the `column` command.

For example with this command:

```
docker inspect $(docker ps -q) --format "{{.Name}} {{.Config.User}}" | column -t -s ' '
```

Or if you also want some fancy headings:

```
(echo "NAME USER"; docker inspect $(docker ps -q) --format "{{.Name}} {{.Config.User}}") | column -t -s ' '
```